# Creating commands with multiple arguments pick one

Tags: python, python-click

I'm trying to create a Click based command line interface, and I've found CLI to be sufficient, however I can't seem to figure out how I should design it. So far I have the below code which creates 4 commands. However what I ideally want is something like this:

```
commands:
cli.py env delete NAME
cli.py env list
cli.py source delete NAME
cli.py source list
```

my current code:

```
@click.group()
@click.version_option()
def cli():
    """First paragraph.
    """

@cli.command()
def list_env():
    "list env"

@cli.command()
def delete_env(name):
    "Delete enviroment"

@cli.command()
def list_source():
    "list source"

def delete_source(name):
    "Delete source"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Comment: So whats the specific question?

Comment: is it possible to create such structure where you have one command for instance `source` and then multiple arguments `list` and `delete`, where you only can pick one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be done with sub-groups.  The key is to declare two more groups (ie: `env` and `source`) that are sub-groups of `cli`, and then the commands (ie: `list` and `delete`) will be associated with the sub-groups like:

#### Code:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.version_option()
def cli():
    """First paragraph.
    """

@cli.group()
def env():
    """env sub-command"""

@env.command('list')
def list_():
    click.echo("env list")

@env.command()
@click.argument('name')
def delete(name):
    click.echo("env delete %s" % name)

@cli.group()
def source():
    """source sub-command"""

@source.command('list')
def list_():
    click.echo("source list")

@source.command()
@click.argument('name')
def delete(name):
    click.echo("source delete %s" % name)
```

#### Test Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #cli('env list'.split())
    cli('env delete a_name'.split())
    #cli('source list'.split())
    #cli('source delete a_name'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
env delete a_name
```